# Adding indents to the ToC without adding dotted lines between sections

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, amsart

I wanted to add indents to format my ToC so I added the tocloft package I saw recommended on other threads.  Now the indentation is perfect, but there is a dotted line in between each section in the actual body of the article.  For example, it shows:

> 1.1 Method.
>
> 1.1 ......................................

Before it would have only shown that first line, not the second line with the second set of numbers and the dotted line.  How do I get rid of that?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Experiment 1}
\subsection{Method}
\subsubsection{Participants}
\subsubsection{Stimuli}
\subsubsection{Procedure}
\subsection{Results}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem.

Comment: The package `tocloft` is incompatible with `amsart`. The class `amsart` is a special class and should only use for papers of AMS. I recommend to use the class `scrartlc` or `memoir` with the option `article`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`amsart` and `tocloft` are not compatible. You can either use another document class or, if you want to continue using `amsart`, you'll need to redefine `\l@section`, `\l@subsection`, and `\l@subsubsection`, `\tocsection`, `\tocsubsection`, and `\tocsubsubsection`; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\l@section{\@tocline{1}{0pt}{1pc}{}{}}
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{1pc}{4.6em}{}}
\def\l@subsubsection{\@tocline{3}{0pt}{1pc}{7.6em}{}}
\renewcommand{\tocsection}[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\makebox[2.3em][l]{%
    \ignorespaces#1 #2.\hfill}}}#3}
\renewcommand{\tocsubsection}[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\hspace*{2.3em}\makebox[2.3em][l]{%
    \ignorespaces#1 #2.\hfill}}}#3}
\renewcommand{\tocsubsubsection}[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\hspace*{4.6em}\makebox[3em][l]{%
    \ignorespaces#1 #2.\hfill}}}#3}
\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Experiment 1}
\subsection{Method}
\subsubsection{Participants}
\subsubsection{Stimuli}
\subsubsection{Procedure}
\subsection{Results}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  That's perfect.  Can you explain to me what those lines you added mean or direct me somewhere that will explain it?

Comment: @emily `\l@section`, `\l@subsection`, and `\l@subsubsection` control how each sectional unit entry will be typeset in the ToC; they use `\@tocline` which is specific for the AMS-family of document classes (the original definitions can be found in the file `amsart.cls`) and this command controls the level and spacing for each entry in the ToC; `\tocsection`, `\tocsubsection`, `\tocsubsubsection` are also defined in `amsart.cls` and give you even more control (you can, for example, easily change the indention) over the entries.

Comment: @emily All those commands can be found in `amsart.cls` but, unfortunately, the AMS document classes code is not very well commented. By the way, since my answer seems to have solved your proble, please consider accepting it; in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).